# Avoid already existing objects when importing into Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, impdp

I need help with `impdp`. I have taken a backup with:

```
expdp system/pw@orcl full=y directory=abc dumpfile=full.dmp
```

Now I need to import the dump into another instance, which has recently been created. I was going to import the full database dump, but it raises an error when an object already exists.

However, these objects belong to Oracle's default schemas, which I can not remove. How do I avoid these import errors?

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the schemas with the `exclude` parameter. E.g:

```
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:\"IN\(\'SYS\',\'SYSTEM\',\'OUTLN\',\'ORDDATA\',\'OLAPSYS\',\'MDDATA\',\'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR\',\'ANONYMOUS\',\'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR\',\'ANONYMOUS\',\'FLOWS_FILES\',\'APEX_PUBLIC_USER\',\'APEX_030200\',\'OWBSYS\',\'OWBSYS_AUDIT\',\'SCOTT\',\'SYSMAN\',\'MGMT_VIEW\'\)\"
```

The list of schemas depends on the database version and options installed.

In a parameterfile, you can use the above without `\` (escaping special characters).

Comment: i know that way . but is it good to do because currently we have around 30 oracle default users

Comment: @ws That is normal if you have multiple additional options installed.

Comment: its works good . but is there anything to find out default users because there is still some users are different from other instance

Comment: @ws Here is the list of default users in version 11.2: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/rev_precon_db.htm#BDCIADFH

Comment: ok thanks @ Balazs Papp , that means i have to write all username at least once in parameter file

Comment: Maybe you are looking through the wrong end of the telescope.  Instead of trying to skip an extensive list of 'default' schemas, you just use the SCHEMAS parameter to list what should be relatively few application schemas.

Comment: Yes, @ EdStevens , that is also a good option but i have number of application schema as well :) , but now its ok thanks for the same